# List iterator not incrementable when checking collision between objects

Tags: c++, cinder

I am currently coding a space shooter with cinder to learn c++. I am checking collisions between the lasers and the enemys.

```
void ParticleController::CheckCollisions()
{

  for(std::list<Enemy>::iterator e = enemys_.begin(); e != enemys_.end();)
  {
      for(std::list<LaserParticle>::iterator p = laserParticles_.begin(); p != laserParticles_.end();)
      {
          if(e->GetBoundingBox().intersects(p->GetBoundingBox()))
          {
              e = enemys_.erase(e);
              p = laserParticles_.erase(p);
          }

          else
            ++p;
      }   

      ++e;
  }
}
```

But I get the error "list iterator not incrementable". I had this error before, but I cant seem to fix it this time.

Comment: You probably get this error when you try to increment further than .end()

Comment: @Elliot Robinson the answer on that question doesnt apply to my case

Comment: It should be an exact application in the case where all enemies are hit by a lasers, since your `++e` is not conditional on `e != enemys_.end()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely it happens when you just have erased the last enemy. In that case erase returns end() and e cannot be incremented anymore.

```
if (e != enemys_.end())
  ++e;
```